# Setting a style in WPF as property attribute

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controls, wpf-controls, styles

This seems like extremely easy question, but I do not know how I will go about doing it.

I know you can set the property of a object by using the following syntax

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"/>
```

However, is it possible to set the style property using this syntax.

```
<Button>
        <Button.Style>
            WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) for `StaticResource` shows you how to do that:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="SomeStyle" />
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: You seem to be answering all of my questions =)